# RuntimeError: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight 96 3 11 11, but got 2-dimensional input of size [30, 50176] instead

Tags: python, pytorch

I had a doubt with regard to a problem I'm working on . I'm trying to use Alexnet on the At&t ORL face dataset on google colab.

I'm getting the error while training the model-

> RuntimeError: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight 96 3 11 11, but got 2-dimensional input of size [30, 50176] instead

Here is the Colab file - [Here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jAtA-jMR9W87UaKv7UPqWstGRVG3ZuqV)
Can anyone please suggest what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: expected 2D or 3D input (got 1D input) PyTorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53500511/valueerror-expected-2d-or-3d-input-got-1d-input-pytorch)

Comment: you need to add a singleton "batch" dimension